# Dropping and recreating database, along with tables

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a database whose structure I'm happy with, but which has a fair amount of dummy data in it. I would like to drop and recreate the database while at the same time wiping out the tables, but retain the table structures and relationships.

When I right-click on the database and choose to script 'drop and create' statements they're for the database itself, but no mention of the tables within-- unless I'm missing something.

Is it possible to generate a script that drops/creates a database and the tables within?  I can individually select each table and script out their drop/create statements and order things so it will work, but are there other ways of doing this in one swoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a localized version of `Sql Server 2008 R2`, so some of my instructions could be imprecise.
I hope that there are no big differences.

- Right click on your database and select `Tasks` and then `Generate Scripts`
- Leave the first option selected (Build script for all db and objects) and select next
- On the second page click `Advanced`
- Select the option to `Build Script for DROP & CREATE`
- Select the option to `Use only the Schema` (not Schema and Data)
- Check the other options you would like to use.
- Finally choose your save options and click Next until SSMS creates the script

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that you should do this. That way you can select different tables or stored procedure to script for. See MSDN [How to: Generate a Script (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on how to do it step-by-step.

```
Right click on DB_Name -> select tasks -> Generate Scripts
```

[image]